# Should my database be on the same server as my web server?

Tags: postgresql, configuration

We are about to add user login and management to a high traffic website.  I am wondering if I should put the postgres database on the same server or put it in a different node in the internal networked setup.

Reason I have been thinking of this is I believe the database would be more secure if it was only accessible via internal networking.

Comment: So you know there are reasons not to do it. Can you find reasons why you _should_ place them on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons as to why it is advisable to have your database exist on a separate server to your web application.

In my opinion chief amongst these are the security implications. For instance a simplistic network architecture would see your web server in a DMZ, or public subnet, and your database server in a private subnet. The web server can accept inbound traffic from the untrusted internet (providing you are not using a load balancer etc.) whereas your database subnet only accepts inbound traffic from the public subnet.

For more info see this similar stack overflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659970/why-is-it-not-advisable-to-have-the-database-and-web-server-on-the-same-machine). 
The second point in the top answer around scalability is also a key argument to bare in mind.